# MVC3 Resource not found - Default area page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, global-asax, asp.net-mvc-areas

This is an odd one.

A web app which I've been working on for a number of months has worked absolutely fine up until two days ago.

The basic structure in question comprises of a number of Areas (the main issue concerning the "Admin" area), a default Controller/View at the highest level of the MVC project and  Castle.Windsor DI plumbing.

Out of the blue the default page for the Admin section now displays a "resource not found" message. This message is independant of whether i access this page via a RedirectToAction (after login) or via a standard return View(...) via menu system.

Does anyone have any reason why this particular route is no longer valid? Or whats going on here?

NB: 
- The other area default routes map correctly still
- I am able to access every other page by using the direct url into the address bar.
- The default route for admin (and the 8 others i require) appear fine in the route table

Global.asax stuff:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterModelBinders();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(_container));

        BoostrapContainer();
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
    }
```

Admin Area registration:

```
public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Admin";
            }
        }

public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "AdminDashboard", action = "AdminDashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

    );
}
```

- worth noting for the admin registration i've tried specifying the namespace explicitly with a:

  new { "xx.xx.xx.xx.Admin" }

But no luck.

However, trying to type localhost/Admin results still in a resource not found.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [RouteDebugger Phil Haack wrote](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx), and ensure that when you go to that route, it's not hitting another route first.

Routes are a 'top one wins' affair. This includes Area registration. The RouteDebugger will show you what order it thinks the routes are in.

Make your admin route this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin Dashboard Route",
    "admin",
    new { area = admin, controller = "admindashboard", action = "dashboard" }
);
```

and place that in your area registration.

It should resolve your issue.

The problem is that your route isn't specific enough.

It wants, "Admin/something/something", and the code is saying, "Well, if "admin"/blank comes in, that doesn't match the "admin/something/something" route, but it does match the "default" route.  It looks at the number of segments you have filled in, as well as what (or what's not) in them.

Comment: Hi George, I have installed the NuGet debugger that Phil wrote already. Whilst it works perfectly for the initial Login page, and displays the corect routes of which the admin_default exists, once i click login, (or alternatively from another page) because the resource is not found, the debugging information is lost?

Comment: You don't want to use the one that works as a 'control' rather you want it to intercept the calls by placing the configuration for it in your global.asax.  Since you can't get to the page, the one that works as a control is not going to help you here.

Comment: We also need to see all your routes and the URLs you're trying to hit.

Comment: Update question with routes using the control version. However, i cannot type the localhost<foo>/Admin url in because it results in a resource not found still. But from the initial page i can see that the route is registered correctly... would you not agree? I can do screenshot if its easier to read.

Comment: Your problems aren't very clear. what do you mean by typing in `localhost<foo>/admin`? What does that mean?  Also, you **don't** want to use the control version. You want to use it such that all calls are intercepted and sent to the route debugger page (if you read Phil Haack's directions, you need to register the app in your `Application_start` and then re-run the app. When you type in the URL that you think should work, it'll show you why it isn't working.

Comment: Right, yes, im using the interceptor version of the route debugger in the application_start. I'm describing the URL i think should work: in this instance "http://localhost:46724/Admin" which, as i've updated in my question, is registered as a valid route, with defaults. However, when running the app with or without the debugger i do not get either a valid page, nor route debug information, however it presents a resource not found screen."Requested URL: /Admin/"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7388/discussion-between-matt-tolliday-and-george-stocker)